# PHP CodeIgniter - Singing out after cookie expires but page remains, what to do?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, cookies

I didn't know what to put in the title because I find the situation a little complex and awkward.

I have an interface to which you can sign-in, and there is a dashboard. There is an input there that let's you search for items in the database, and the results are returned via $.ajax.

Now, if the user remains on the page for too long, their cookie expires, but they're still on the page. So when they type something in the input, the "is_logged_in()" gets triggered, returns false, and spits out the login screen, just like it should.

But because the ajax is loading whatever content is returned into a certain div, it ends up loading the entire login window *inside* the area where the searched-for items are supposed to be appearing, if that makes sense.

I considered using JavaScript to read the returned data before loading it into the div, but I am trying to avoid using JS to redirect unless it's absolutely necessary.

Any way around this?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check session every N seconds. And if session is expired just reload the page. The code above check if session is expired every 5 seconds.

---

**JS**

```
var check_session;
function CheckForSession() {
        var str="chksession=true";
        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sec.php",
                data: str,
                cache: false,
                success: function(res){
                    if(res == "1") {
                    alert('Your session has expired');
                    }
                }
        });
}
check_session = setInterval(CheckForSession, 5000);
```

**sec.php**

```
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION["your_session"];
if($name == '')
{
    //session expired
    echo "1";
} else {
    //session not expired
    echo "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has a build in method to detect ajax request:

```
$this->input->is_ajax_request();
```

What you can do is:

1. Make an ajax request
2. Check if is_ajax_request and not logged in
3. If so, send something like "denied" to the ajax site
4. Make a redirect via javascript if incoming data === "denied"